# Proper RESTful API practice to run 2 queries in a function?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, rest

So I'm developing an API for mySQL with nodejs. Trying to make a function that inserts into two different tables.

```
INSERT INTO account_details (username, first_name, last_name, gender, mobile_number, postal_code, email, activated) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

and

```
INSERT INTO passwords (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)
```

What's the proper way to do it?

Right now I have this, which works perfectly except it crashes my nodejs server, giving the error below.

```
    addUser(request, respond) {
        var userObject = new User(request.body.username, request.body.password, request.body.first_name, request.body.last_name, request.body.gender, request.body.mobile_number, request.body.postal_code, request.body.email, request.body.activated, null, null);
        var sql = "INSERT INTO account_details (username, first_name, last_name, gender, mobile_number, postal_code, email, activated) " +
                    "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        var password = "INSERT INTO passwords (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";

        var values = [userObject.getUsername(), userObject.getFirstName(), userObject.getLastName(), userObject.getGender(),
                    userObject.getMobileNumber(), userObject.getPostalCode(), userObject.getEmail(), userObject.getActivated()];

        var passvalues = [userObject.getUsername(), userObject.getPassword()];

        db.query(sql, values, function (error, result) {
            if (error) {
                throw error;
            }
            else {
                respond.json(result);
            }
        });
        db.query(password, passvalues, function (error, result) {
            if (error) {
                throw error;
            }
            else {
                respond.json(result);
            }
        });
    }
```

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Can anyone help with the proper syntax? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your code as below:

```
addUser(request, respond) {
    var userObject = new User(request.body.username, request.body.password, request.body.first_name, request.body.last_name, request.body.gender, request.body.mobile_number, request.body.postal_code, request.body.email, request.body.activated, null, null);
    var sql = "INSERT INTO account_details (username, first_name, last_name, gender, mobile_number, postal_code, email, activated) " +
                "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    var password = "INSERT INTO passwords (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";

    var values = [userObject.getUsername(), userObject.getFirstName(), userObject.getLastName(), userObject.getGender(),
                userObject.getMobileNumber(), userObject.getPostalCode(), userObject.getEmail(), userObject.getActivated()];

    var passvalues = [userObject.getUsername(), userObject.getPassword()];

    db.query(sql, values, function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        }
        else {
            db.query(password, passvalues, function (error, result) {
              if (error) {
                throw error;
              }
              else {
                respond.json(result);
              }
            });
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: isn't this will make it twice as slow?

Comment: @Tuan Anh Tran Anyway he needs result to be send after the 2 db operations are done

Comment: he can do it in parallel. say first query take 9 second and second one takes 10 second. doing it sequentially will take 19 seconds whereas doing it in parallel will take only 10 second.

Comment: @Tuan Anh Tran I accept what you are suggesting. But my solution is inline with the way how he is implenmented.

Comment: @Nicholas Kee Plz consider what `Tuan Anh Tran` is suggested. Use async await for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're doing it twice

```js
respond.json(result);
```

first one will succeed and the second one will throw the above error.

what you want to do is to wait for both of them to succeed and return result.

Consider using Promises and await both of those and then proceed to response.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've never touched promises though so I will look into it.